# Problem Solving Question - A sidewalk being built around a garden

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, word-problem

> We have a garden that measures $17$ feet by $20$ feet. We want to pour cement for a $3$-foot-wide sidewalk around the garden. To make the forms for the cement, we will need to buy some $2$-by-$4$-inch lumber. How many feet of lumber will we need just for the perimeter of the walk? (Consider both the inside and outside perimeter.)

#### My solution:

I drew a picture of a garden and a sidewalk being built around the outside. The height of the inside (garden) was $17$ feet, and the width was $20$ feet. Then, I made a $3$-foot corner around all four corners of the garden. So, the height of the exterior was $17 + 3 + 3 = 23$ feet, while the width was $3 + 3 + 20 = 26$ feet. So, the perimeter of the inside is $74$ feet, and the perimeter of the outside is $98$ feet. I added these two to get $172$ feet as the total perimeter. Inexorably, I deemed that $172$ feet of lumber was needed for the perimeter of the walk. Is that safe to assume or am I misinterpreting the question/what it is asking for? I am getting a bit "tripped up" of the fact that the problem gave me that, "to make the forms for the cement, we will need to buy some $2$-by-$4$-inch lumber."

If anyone else cares to work out the problem/verify my solution, that would be nice.

Comment: 2x4 lumber can actually be any length; the 2 and 4 refer to width and thickness. So, you're right.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just wanted a quick check.

Comment: Depends: are you meant to assume that you can subtract a total of 8 inches from the inside and 8 inches from the outside due to the thickness of the planks?

Comment: Hard to know, depends on how you handle corners. Might need $2$ extra inches at each corner, actually not quite $2$ since a two by four is less than $2$ inches thick.

Comment: In all likelihood yours is the desired answer, if this is a textbook question. As a couple of the commenters have noted, a practical real-world answer would have to take a bit more into account.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I see there are many unaccounted for things when resembling this to a real-world problem. Alas, it is simply a textbook problem, so my answer should be sufficient - I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct: consider the following diagram.

[image]

So the sum of the interior and exterior perimeters of the concrete is $2 \times 17 + 2 \times 20 + 2 \times 23 + 2 \times 26  = 172 \text{ feet}.$

So long as the edging has constant width $w$ (2 inches, 4 inches, something else), this remains true; what you save on the inside, you need on the outside.  So the length needed as shown in the diagram is $2 \times (17-2w) + 2 \times 20 + 2 \times 23 + 2 \times (26+2w)  = 172 \text{ feet}$ again.

Comment: Nice diagram. Makes sense - slightly quicker/easier way to the solution!